# Change default stock in Magento2

Tags: magento, adobe, e-commerce, magento2, stock

I am trying to change the default stock in Magento2 but i can not find any option for doing that. What i want to reach is that i want to equalize the attribute Quantity and Default Stock.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMPL2.png)

In this picture you are able to see the option to change the quantity.

I have tried it already by increasing the number of articles that are on stock, but nothing changed. I was thinking that **Quantity - Notification Number = Default Stock**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVBDF.png)

But as you see here the default stock number is still remaining at 1.

Answer (score 0):

The default stock and the default source are hardcoded. On the edit product page, under the "Sources" section, you can see the assigned sources list that was reset by the import process most likely. This data is stored in the inventory_source_item database table. Make sure that your import doesn't overwrite sources.